# browserstack reports with protractor

Tags: selenium, jasmine, report, protractor, browserstack

I'm using browserstack hub to run protractor. I have been looking for a good report without luck, I want a report containing the browsers tested and the platform, is there something like following using protractor, jasmine and browserstack ?

[image]

Would be great if we can have in the left the test name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can recall, there is no mature reporter that can aggregate results from different capabilities. There is that [`protractor-multicapabilities-htmlreporter_v2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-multicapabilities-htmlreporter_v2) that is close to what you are asking about, but it's not active at the moment and is not widely used:

[image]

You can also dump test results with `JUnitXmlReporter` ([separate report for each browser/capability](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters#multi-capabilities)) and then postprocess the results and create a combined report. There is [`junit-xml-parser` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-xml-parser) that would help you to parse the `JUnit` XML reports. You would just need some custom logic for aggregation part and creating the resulting report.

But, in general, I really like the idea and also need a similar functionality.

Comment: It's a shame that doesn't exists a mature way to do it, but it will work, thanks.